# Export MMS Term set to sql server database

Tags: managed-metadata

is there any way to export managed metadata term set to another sql server database that not belong to the sharepoint server farm.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do a database backup / restore of the Managed Metadata Service application to the other farm

or

Run a Powershell script see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607667(v=office.15).aspx

or

Use an import / export tool to migrate the term set like http://termsetimporter.codeplex.com/

These options retain the Term Guids whereas if you use the UI in CA you lose them going from one environment to another